# Distinct query not working fine in sqlserver 2005

Tags: sql-server

```
ID              Timestamp
749705      2010-05-10 12:11:00.000
749702      2011-06-25 00:00:00.000
749706      2011-01-01 08:32:00.000
749701      2010-05-10 12:05:00.000
749705      2010-06-19 14:13:00.000
749706      2011-03-19 14:15:00.000
749703      2010-06-28 16:30:00.000
749703      2011-08-04 12:01:00.000
749701      2011-06-15 12:40:00.000
749702      2012-01-11 08:32:00.000
```

Hi,
I have an table like above format where now I need to get the result of distinct ID and max timestamp for that ID.

I tried using the group by function but that is not giving me the result.
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say what is going wrong for you without seeing your query. I think you are looking for something like this.

```
select ID, max(Timestamp) as MaxTimeStamp
from YourTable
group by ID
```

Result:

```
ID          MaxTimeStamp
----------- -----------------------
749701      2011-06-15 12:40:00.000
749702      2012-01-11 08:32:00.000
749703      2011-08-04 12:01:00.000
749705      2010-06-19 14:13:00.000
749706      2011-03-19 14:15:00.000
```